# Creating Zip of directory in Unix m/c

Tags: unix

on Unix m/c i have folder in which there are few more folders..
I wants to make zip file of parent folder. and i should able to unzip this zip file in windows m/c..
Can you please advice..

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 32):

given that the program 'zip' is available, the following should work:

```
zip -r archive_name.zip folder
```

Answer (score 8):

From midnight commander highlight the directory that you want to zip, then press *F2* to get to the user menu, then *@* to perform an operation on it.  You can now enter `zip -r archive.zip` followed by return, where *archive.zip* is that name of the zip file that you want to create.

Answer (score 2):

```
zip -r parent-directory parent-directory
```

If you have zip installed on your Unix host.

It will create parent-directory.zip file and it can be unzipped on Windows using native unzip Windows program.